# How to filter a Boolean mask containing NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have this pandas DataFrame bellow:

```
    Id                          Guild                                     Test
0   5c5dc770f920209b94c3def3    72f92390/7f2e/4b41/b53b/393470619eca      True
1   5c5dc7707d62f8b356457863    596f57d7/c8a9/4b14/aec1/18ef2b9fa940      None
2   5c5dc770974d1a6d38cffa3a    6a7ad94c/0511/4ef9/8b60/e05158cad03c     False
3   5c5dc7709809c3452ae07d22    843d9c5f/1f53/4752/a905/0b1de73efab2      None
4   5c5dc7706c606a2118c4350b    9d63dcc5/1063/49b3/9a90/a854e7eb7398      None
```

**When i tried to apply numpy.where:**

```
pdf['Id'] = np.where(bool(pdf['Test']), pdf['Id'], None)
```

**Also tried using numpy.equal:**

```
pdf['Id'] = np.where(np.equal(pdf['Test'], None), None, pdf['Id'])
```

Throws me the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My goal: Apply None to Id columns where Teste is not a valid boolean.

I've check these similar questions:
[link One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) [Link Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bool` is a Python function that returns a single boolean value.  The `Test` column is a Series, multiple values.  That ambiguity error is the Pandas equivalent of the error that `numpy` produces for `bool(np.array([True, False, True]))` - trying to get on boolean from an array of several.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complication here is that your "boolean" column also has None values.

You can instead compare the "Test" column to `True`.

```
pdf['Id'] = np.where(pdf['Test'] == True, pdf['Id'], None)
pdf    
                         Id                                 Guild   Test
0  5c5dc770f920209b94c3def3  72f92390/7f2e/4b41/b53b/393470619eca   True
1                      None  596f57d7/c8a9/4b14/aec1/18ef2b9fa940   None
2                      None  6a7ad94c/0511/4ef9/8b60/e05158cad03c  False
3                      None  843d9c5f/1f53/4752/a905/0b1de73efab2   None
4                      None  9d63dcc5/1063/49b3/9a90/a854e7eb7398   None
```

Or, assign using `loc`.

```
pdf.loc[pdf['Test'] != True, 'Id'] = None
pdf    
                         Id                                 Guild   Test
0  5c5dc770f920209b94c3def3  72f92390/7f2e/4b41/b53b/393470619eca   True
1                      None  596f57d7/c8a9/4b14/aec1/18ef2b9fa940   None
2                      None  6a7ad94c/0511/4ef9/8b60/e05158cad03c  False
3                      None  843d9c5f/1f53/4752/a905/0b1de73efab2   None
4                      None  9d63dcc5/1063/49b3/9a90/a854e7eb7398   None
```

Comment: Thank you @coldspeed,

I'd guessed it would work cuz when you simply do this:
`x = None
bool(x)`

It's return False, but in this case we're comparing a simple variable. I guess it wont work on pandas, since we're using `pandas.Series`, acording this answer:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) 

However, this solution works for me. Thank you!